# Secure Data in Firebase - Firepad Example

Tags: web-applications, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules, firepad

I am currently developing a web app on Firebase that uses Firepad as one of the tools.

Everything was working fine until I tried to secure the realtime database with rules. Here are the new rules

```
 {
  "rules": {
        "allmembers":{
        ".read":"auth != null",
          ".write":"auth != null && !data.exists() && newData.exists()"
      },

  "orgs":{

    "$org":{ 
      ".read": "data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",

          "info":{
          }, 
         "members":{
          },

        "processes":{
           "$process":{
                "bpm":{
              },
              "firepad":{
              }
           }   
        }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

To put it short, the idea is to keep a general record of every member with a single value that is the ID of the organization where they belong, and then use it to give them access to the firm's data.

The rules work well for set/get data of `$org` such as modifying "members" or "bpm" except for `orgs/$org/processes/$process/firepad`.

So why does the console give me this warning and firepad cannot read and write data in firebase database?

`FIREBASE WARNING: set at /orgs/1/processes/processus/firepad/users/0xcNuXRLk0g2fedKfH35qLFxy9R2/cursor failed: permission_denied`

EDIT: Here the example that I currently use and works. However, with the rule `".read":true`, everyone can access to Firepad of other orgs?

```
{  
  "rules":{  
    "orgs":{  
      "$org":{  
        ".read":"data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write":"data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        "info":{  

        },
        "members":{  

        },
        "processes":{  
          "$process":{  
            "bpm":{  

            },
            "firepad":{  
              "history":{  
                ".read":true
              },
              "checkpoint":{  
                ".read":true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an errant "processus" in your path:

/orgs/1/processes/<del>processus/</del>firepad/users/0xcNuXRLk0g2fedKfH35qLFxy9R2/cursor

Comment: Hi, "processus" corresponds to $process. The only way that I found for fireapad to work is adding ".read":true to the childs "checkpoint" and "history" of firepad, see the edit.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The rules were hard to read with the way they were indented...  I've reformatted them and see that you're correct. The rules look fine to me...  which makes me wonder if perhaps there's a timing issue where perhaps you're initializing firepad before you're logged in or something.  One way to check would be to listen for the auth state changed event and log a message when you get logged in. If you get that message before the permission denied error, then you probably need to re-order your firepad initialization. In any case, seeing a full example (on jsbin or whatever) would help.